# How to create multiple coropra in R

Tags: r, loops, nlp

I am trying to create multiple corpora for textanalysis in R.

I started by loading multiple txt files into the working directory.

```
names <- gsub(".txt", "", filenames)
for (i in 1:length(filenames)){ 
d <- readtext(filenames[i], encoding = "UTF-8") 
assign(names[i], d) }
```

Now my goal is to create a corpus for each individual file, without having to do it for each file individually.

I tried two versions:

```
all_txts <- list.files(pattern = ".txt$")
lapply(all_txts, function(x){
  c <- corpus()})
```

and

```
for ( i in 1: length(ls(pattern =".txt"))){
  e <- corpus(i)
  assingn(filenames[i], "_corpus")}
```

in both cases I got the error message:

```
Error in corpus.default() : corpus() only works on character, corpus, Corpus, data.frame, kwic objects.
```

My end goal is to tokenize the corpora and get an Excel-Sheet for every txt file which is split up by sentence.

Thanks for your help in andvance

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! A reproducible example makes it much easier for us to help you ! Also, look at what the `corpus()` function takes as arguments (eg, with `?corpus`). You are either giving it nothing or a number, which according to your error, is not what it expects

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think you should be able to reproduce that by using any txt-files you may have on your computer or one from the internet.                                Yes, the corpus() function only takes data.frames and character vectors and I think that list.files produces a character with only the names of the documents which is why the code does not work. But I do not know how to give it the correct data type. The corpus() argument works fine on the individual documents but when I try and use it on multiple documents at once.